# Render array passed from Express with Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Most of the questions pertaining to this all seem to be about passing the server-side JS object into a client-side JS object. Maybe I'm missing something, but all I want to do is render HTML using the server-side JS object.

On the server:

```
app.get '/', (req, res) ->

  res.render 'index',
    data:
      keywords: [
        'one'
        'two'
      ]
```

Using [these](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a9) docs, none of what's below works in the `index.jade` file:

```
- var keywords = [#{data.keywords}]
each kw in keywords
  li= kw

- var keywords = ["#{data.keywords}"]
each kw in keywords
  li= kw

- var keywords = "#{data.keywords}"
each kw in keywords
  li= kw

- var keywords = #{data.keywords}
each kw in keywords
  li= kw
```

The array *does* print to a string when I do:

```
p "#{data.keywords}"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about

```
each kw in data.keywords
  li= kw
```

?

Comment: Well, shoot. I didn't even think of that. I assumed all data passed had to be interpolated. Yup :) Thanks! Will be a few minutes before I can accept.